# SpiRawSqlService not found setting up EBean in a Spigot plugin

Tags: java, classloader, minecraft, ebean, spigot

### Overview

I set up a [github repo](https://github.com/amp7368/BukkitEBeanExample/tree/problem-description/output) for this question to provide as much of the boiled down environment as possible.

My goal is to set up [ebean](https://ebean.io/) ORM for database manangement from a [Paper Minecraft](https://papermc.io/) plugin. I'm able to shade in the ebean dependencies, but creating a query using "io.ebean:ebean-querybean:" throws an error saying that it cannot find an implementation of SpiRawSqlService.

### Environment

Paper Minecraft: paper-1.19.3-367.jar
Java 18
Ebean enhancement plugin for IntelliJ(I checked that I have it enabled for this project)
io.ebean gradle plugin version 13.10.0
shadowJar gradle plugin version 7.1.2

### The Stacktrace

Everything is fine setting up the database, and saving to the Database. Queries without using a querybean work fine as well. The error is thrown when initializing any [class containing a reference](https://github.com/amp7368/BukkitEBeanExample/blob/problem-description/output/src/stripped.FindByQueryBean.java) to a generated querybean.
The error outputted is printed the [latest.log](https://github.com/amp7368/BukkitEBeanExample/blob/problem-description/output/latest.log)
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No service implementation found for interface org.example.ebean.io.ebean.service.SpiRawSqlService`

The stacktrace tells us that it couldn't find `org.example.ebean.io.ebean.service.SpiRawSqlService`.
Looking at the decompiled shadowJar after package relocation, the implementation for this class is found at `org.example.ebean.io.ebeaninternal.server.rawsql.DRawSql`;

Printing out the ClassLoader#getDefinedPackages on the instance supplied when creating the ebean Database connection results in this:

```
org.example.ebean
org.example.ebean.database
org.example.ebean.io.ebean
org.example.ebean.io.ebean.annotation
org.example.ebean.io.ebean.config
org.example.ebean.io.ebean.config.dbplatform
org.example.ebean.io.ebean.datasource
org.example.ebean.io.ebean.meta
```

As you can see, the `org.example.ebean.io.ebeaninternal` package and subpackages are not outputted in this list.

### Underlying issue

How/where is the package "ebeaninternal" being loaded if at all? How can I get the enhanced querybean to find this package so it can load the implementation (DRawSql) of SpiRawSqlService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reasoning

Bukkit's @EventHandler utilizes a different contextClassLoader than the ClassLoader that loads the ebean classes/services (contained in the ShadowJar).

The error states `No service implementation found` because the thread that is initializing the querybean does not have access to that class.

### Explained Solution

The solution here is to use `Thread#setContextClassLoader()` to use the same ClassLoader used when calling `DatabaseFactory.createWithContextClassLoader()`. Set the ClassLoader, initialize every Class that uses a QueryBean, revert the ClassLoader to what it originally was.

EBean might be able to solve this problem. But for now, a fix is to just call an empty init method on every class that becomes an Enhanced-QueryBean from a thread that is using the proper ContextClassLoader

### Full Example

I pushed the full example containing the fix to the original [github repo](https://github.com/amp7368/BukkitEBeanExample/tree/problem-description/output)

### Basic Example

##### DatabaseSetup.java

```
    public static void load() {
        DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig = configureDataSource();
        DatabaseConfig dbConfig = configureDatabase(dataSourceConfig);

        // We should use the classloader that loaded this plugin
        // because this plugin has our ebean dependencies
        ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = BukkitEBeanPlugin.class.getClassLoader();

        // create the DatabaseFactory with the classloader containing ebean dependencies
        DatabaseFactory.createWithContextClassLoader(dbConfig, pluginClassLoader);

        // Set the current thread's contextClassLoader to the classLoader with the ebean dependencies
        // This allows the class to initialize itself with access to the required class dependencies
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);

        // invoke the static initialization of every class that contains a querybean.
        // Note that any method in the class will initialize the class.
        FindByQueryBean.init();

        // Restore the contextClassLoader to what it was originally
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassLoader);

        BukkitEBeanPlugin.get().getLogger().info("Successfully created database");
    }
    ...
}
```

##### FindByQueryBean.java

```
public static void init() {
    // intentionally empty
}
```